# how to get checkbox value in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

can you please tell me a way to get checkbox value in angular 2

here is my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grtvc7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

one way I know how to do that using the template variable like this

```
<mat-checkbox #ch>Check me!</mat-checkbox>

  checkCheckBoxvalue(ele){
    console.log(ele.checked)
  }
```

I want to know another way to achieve this functionality

Comment: If you go to the examples pane of the documentation they show how to bind to it. https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you need to use `change` event

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="checkCheckBoxvalue($event)">Check me!</mat-checkbox>

checkCheckBoxvalue(event){
    console.log(event.checked)
  }
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-id52ev?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

## other ways -

- You can use two way data binding for the same like mentioned below -

  ```
  <input type="checkbox" name="myData" [(ngModel)]="isChecked">
  ```
- You can use a local variable as well and fetch the value in controller side like below -

  ```
  <input type="checkbox" name="myData" #myCheckbox>

  @ViewChild('myCheckbox') myCheckbox;
  console.log(myCheckbox, 'Value of checkbox');
  ```
- Other way is you can use formControl for the same, either it can be model-driven form or template-driven form.

Answer (score 18):

Use change event.target.checked.

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="checkCheckBoxvalue($event)">Check me!</mat-checkbox>

checkCheckBoxvalue(event){
   console.log(event.target.checked)
}
```

Answer (score 13):

bind an [ngModel] to the checkbox

```js
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked">


const isChecked : boolean;
```

Comment: OP is using angular material's checkbox

Comment: I'm not using Angular Material, so this solution worked for me perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ngModel` as you already have imported `FormsModule`. Thats the recommended way.
Check my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2mmwx8)

Here is some code also

## View

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkBoxValue" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
<button (click)="checkCheckBoxvalue()">check check box value</button>
```

## Component

```
checkBoxValue: any = false;
checkCheckBoxvalue(){
    console.log(this.checkBoxValue)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use (change) or component const

```
//template
<input type="checkbox" (click)="doAction($event)">

//component
doAction(event:any){
  console.log(event.target.checked)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

**Using Template-Driven Form**

**1. Creating Checkbox**

We need to use ngModel as an attribute in checkbox so that they can be registered with NgForm directive.

Create checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tc" ngModel>
```

**2. Fetch Value on Form Submit**

When we submit the form and suppose the form value is stored in the instance of NgForm as form then we can fetch checkbox value using form.controls[...] as given below.

```
this.user.isTCAccepted = form.controls['tc'].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the state of a mat-checkbox directly inside your template like following, e.g. to conditionally display a form-control based on state of checkbox:

```
     <mat-checkbox
            #checkbox
            formControlName="hybridPlugin"
            >Checkbox
     </mat-checkbox>

     <mat-form-field *ngIf="checkbox.checked">
         // ...
     </mat-form-field>
```

This works by using template variable #checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

as you already have a local reference `#c` you can use it on the component ts file when needed

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('c') checkbox;

// when needed 
//this.checkbox.value
```

you can call it on form submit or on change event of the checkbox itself.

Comment: Why to use local variable when we have builtin function for the same isn't it?